# Convert PXELINUX to gPXE

Tags: pxe-boot

I have a current working PXELINUX setup, with menu for different OS version.
Recently I tried to add VMware installer to it.
It was looking great up to a point where I was not able to load the required files. VMware itself says using TFTP for downloading all the files is not the best option, especially if you have a high load network, and they recommend using HTTP/gPXE for this.

So I was looking at implementing gPXE.
But all my several tries so far were not working, and I'm not sure what the problem is at this point.

For a start I changed the filename in the DHCP config to point to gpxelinux.0 instead of pxelinux.0
System is booting, showing gPXE, but not processing further.
It is getting a DHCP and then shows

`No filename or root path specified`

I also tried to chainload gPXE from the PXELINUX config, which came back with the same errors.

I read some docs in regards to gPXE, and they all are using a HTTP source for the filename in the DHCP config.
I tried that next, but it is already showing me TFTP errors

`PXE-T01: File not found
PXE-E3B: TFTP Error - File Not found`

At this point I'm not sure what else to try.
I already copied the whole TFTP to the HTTP server, tried using gPXE scripts which will rewrite the source using DHCP option 209/210.
But they all fail because I cannot load it in the DHCP config using HTTP.

Can anybody give me some hints on where to look for errors, or how I could convert my current PXELINUX to gPXE.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I was playing around, and finally got it working.
Was an error in the DHCP config.
Here is what I'm using now:

`class "pxeclients" {
  match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
  if exists user-class and option user-class = "gPXE" {
    filename "http://10.140.160.203/boot.gpxe";
  } else {
    next-server 10.140.160.203;
    filename "/gpxelinux.0";
  }
}`

And the boot.gpxe is chain loading my pxelinux config

`#!gpxe
imgfree
chain http://10.140.160.203/vesamenu.c32 http://10.140.160.203/pxelinux.cfg/default`

Is this a good approach, or is there something else to be aware off?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to move to gPXE as **lpxelinux.0** (Syslinux 6.03) supports http transfers.

Also if you are installing VMware VMvisor (i.e. VMware-VMvisor-Installer-6.0.0-2494585.x86_64.iso) you can do it just by regular TFTP if you correctly set your environment. i.e. if you are trying to install it using an iso and the **memdisk** technique you will surely fail. instead you can use the **mboot** approach; from [Serva's](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html#hypervisor) site:

```
kernel   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/mboot.c32
append   = -c /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/BOOT.CFG
```

Comment: I used the mboot approach. It was always failing to copy one of the files, returning with a device error, which I concluded to be down to the network traffic and TFTP download. I'm using syslinux 4.05

Comment: if always fails on the same file; I think you are probably having a different problem; check if the file is not corrupted. Vmware components are not big they should TFTP transfer w/o problem.

Comment: Tried using the same ISO in a VMware image, which boots ok. TFTP was pulling data from same loop mounted ISO. But since I got gPXE now working, install is going through.